# Changing the height of a tableview cell dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, uitableview

I'm implementing a tableview that look like facebook newsfeed.

I've done setting the height of tableviewcells dynamically based on the content inside

But now i got a problem that is i want to show ....more after just showing 3 lines of content just like in facebook and after clicking the more button the height of the tableviewcell has to be increased by showing the full content of the tableview cell.

See the screenshots below

[image]

instead of showing all the content i want to show just 3 lines and after that `....more` has to be there and if the more button is clicked, the height of the tableviewcell has to change dynamically

Answer (score 1):

You could truncate your UILabel or change the size of your UITextView and place an adjacent UIButton with the title "more". So when the user clicks on more you would change the height of the cell and the frame of your textView/label and the more button should be hidden.

You could show a UILabel with test using truncating it( Your Text is... ) along with a UIButton place just below that.

So when user would click on the button you could change the property of the label( no. of lines, word wrap, etc) to fit in all the text along with changing the height of cell.

[image]

Comment: could u pls elaborate?

Comment: i want that more button after the truncated text like this 

`djakffajsdlfasdkjf....more`

Comment: So shift it next to label and when more button is tapped then remove it from view.

Comment: in iphone my label width is 300.now how can i show the button next to label?

Comment: So reduce your label width to adjust a button and place your button next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate text hight using :

`-(CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size`

Returns the size of the string if it were rendered and constrained to the specified size.

**Parameters:**

**1) font** : The font to use for computing the string size.

**2) size** : The maximum acceptable size for the string. This value is used to calculate where line breaks and wrapping would occur.

**3) Return Value** : The width and height of the resulting string’s bounding box.

According to this you can update cell height.

Comment: this method is deprecated..... and i'm using `boundingRectWithSize:` method.... but what is want is `....more` by reducing the content and when clicking the full content has to be shown by changing the row height dynamically